# Raspberry Pi transmits corrupted data

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero trying to read GPS data.

With this command:

```
sudo cat /dev/ttyAMA0
```

I get the following correct data:

```
$GPGSV,1,1,0*49
$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
$GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30
$GPGGA,,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*48
$GPGLL,,,,,,V,N*64
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*30
```

But in the Python script:

```
import serial
import time
import string

while True:
    port="/dev/ttyAMA0"
    ser=serial.Serial(port, baudrate=9600, timeout=0.5)
    newdata=ser.readline().strip().decode('UTF-8')
    print(newdata)
```

the data is corrupted:

```
GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*30
SV,1,1,0*49
RMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
PVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30
,,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*48
L,,,,,,V,N*64
```

I've spent two days trying to figure out what went wrong with no success. Any tip is much appreciated.

(RaspberryPi OS Lite didn't have `serial` preinstalled, so I installed it like this:)

```
sudo apt-get install python-serial
```

Comment: Looking at unit tests for `readline` in `python-serial`, it looks like this method returns bytes, not a string, so I'm guessing that you're throwing away data with the `strip()` method. https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/7aeea35429d15f3eefed10bbb659674638903e3a/test/test_readline.py

Comment: @commanderdata Yes the GPS raw data has leading whitespace and new line characters which I don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recreating and reinitialising your serial port in every iteration through the loop. You should do that outside the loop as that is loop-invariant:

```
# Set up serial interface
port="/dev/ttyAMA0"
ser=serial.Serial(port, baudrate=9600, timeout=0.5)

while True:
    # read next line
    newdata = ser.readline().strip().decode('UTF-8')
```

Comment: Wow one never stops doing noob moves :') Thanks my hero